# PyGame snake game not running in PyCharm

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python file for a snake game in PyCharm (Community Edition 2020.2). I am using Python 3.8. When I try to run the file, the Python application tries to open, but is never able to to start the game. I feel like there is something wrong with my interpreter. I used the "which python3" command to figure out where my Python3 was installed and am using that location for my interpreter, but again, the application doesn't open upon running. I have attached a screenshot of my interpreter. Any thoughts on what might be wrong would be great[image]

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm automatically creates a virtual env for your work. That might be the root of your problem. You could look up about that to resolve your problem. I am a bit less familar with virtual-envs. Someone else could give you detailed info but it might be the gist.